# How to submit a vue component in Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to add a custom vue component in a submit form.Here's my blade template code:

```
<form action="/question/{{ $question->id }}" method="post">
<label for="title">Description</label>
<editor-by-vue editcontent='{!! $question->body !!}'></editor-by-vue>
<button type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>
```

component.vue

```
<template>
<vue-editor  v-model="content" :editorToolbar="customToolbar">
    <slot></slot>
</vue-editor>
</template>
<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'
export default {
    props: ['editcontent'],
    components: {
        VueEditor
    },
    mounted() {
        this.content = this.editcontent;
    },
    data() {
        return {
            content: '',
            customToolbar: [
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                ['image', 'code-block']
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The vue2-editor is a rich text text editor component.

When I click the submit button how can I get the content of editor in the request?Anyone can help me?

Comment: You need to set the name-attribute on the element that holds the text. Inspect your HTML and see what's generated by the component. If there is no name-attribute or maybe there is no form-control element like a textarea at all, just create your own hidden field and add the content to it as soon as it changes in your component. Otherwise, posting the data directly from you componen with ajax would certainly be an option, too.

Comment: @Quasdunk you should add that as a response so we can upvote.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Thank you, but it's more of a suggestion on what to try and not a real answer, since I don't know for sure if that works / solves the problem. OP would need to report back if that's how he got it working.

Comment: @Quasdunk That makes things complicate.Just make a form component.

Comment: @Shawn_Rong Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean. If you came up with a good solution for your problem, please post it as an answer and aceept it.

Answer (score 0):

Vue editor just works internal with divs, add a hidden field with your original data

```
<template> 
  <vue-editor  v-model="content" :editorToolbar="customToolbar"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="content" v-bind:value="content" />
     <slot></slot> 
  </vue-editor> 
</template>
```